# Well defined function on a manifold

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that $M$ is a differentiable manifold and let $F:TM\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth map. How to prove that the map $\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial q^2}:TM\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is well defined, i.e. it doesn't depend on coodinates?
Is it enough to show that if $\varphi:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $\varphi(q)=(q^1,...,q^n)$ and $\tilde{\varphi}:\tilde{U}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $\tilde{\varphi}=(\tilde{q}^1,...,\tilde{q}^n)$ are local coordinates that induces coordinates $\Phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tilde{\Phi}:\pi^{-1}(\tilde{U})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$ for the cotangent bundle, then it holds
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial^2 (F\circ\Phi)}{\partial q^h\partial q^k}(\Phi^{-1}(x,v))=\dfrac{\partial^2 (F\circ\tilde{\Phi})}{\partial \tilde{q}^h\partial \tilde{q}^k}(\tilde{\Phi}^{-1}(x,v)).
\end{equation}
Thank you.

Comment: How you define $\partial^2 F/\partial q^2$?

Comment: I may define it as $\dfrac{\partial^2 (F\circ\Phi)}{\partial q^h\partial q^k}(\Phi^{-1}(x,v))$ for every chart, if it is well defined as I'm trying to check.

Comment: That is not a real-valued function right?

Comment: Why not?@SiKucing

Comment: Because you differentiate it wrt specific coordinate $q^k$ and $q^h$. But there're many of them.

Comment: Ah, the function I mean is $\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial q^h\partial q^k}$

Comment: So it's only defined locally on a chart.

Comment: Why? Isn't there a way to define it coordinate-independently?

Comment: I don't know.${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can go on this way:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dfrac{\partial^2 (F\circ\tilde{\Phi})}{\partial \tilde{q}^h\partial \tilde{q}^k}(\tilde{\Phi}^{-1}(x,v))&=\dfrac{\partial^2 (F\circ\Phi\circ\Phi^{-1}\circ\tilde{\Phi})}{\partial \tilde{q}^h\partial \tilde{q}^k}(\tilde{\Phi}^{-1}(x,v))\\
&=\dfrac{\partial^2 (F\circ\Phi)}{\partial q^s\partial q^t}(\Phi^{-1}(x,v))\cdot\dfrac{\partial q^s}{\partial \tilde{q}^h}\dfrac{\partial q^t}{\partial \tilde{q}^k}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: ... which shows that the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: Does it mean that it is not well defined? Because this reminds me that it behaves like a tensor.

Comment: It does indeed mean that that $\dfrac{\partial^2 (F\circ\tilde{\Phi})}{\partial \tilde{q}^h\partial \tilde{q}^k}(\tilde{\Phi}^{-1}(x,v))$ is not well-defined. You asked whether it is true that $$\dfrac{\partial^2 (F\circ\tilde{\Phi})}{\partial \tilde{q}^h\partial \tilde{q}^k}(\tilde{\Phi}^{-1}(x,v))=\dfrac{\partial^2 (F\circ\Phi)}{\partial q^s\partial q^t}(\Phi^{-1}(x,v))$$ It is false because the right hand side is missing a factor.

Comment: Thank you, but maybe I don't get the point yet. Does this imply that the notion of Hessian matrix is not well defined on a manifold? Or better, does this imply that the Hessian of a matrix is not defined like in $\mathbb{R}^N$, but it has to take care of changes of coordinates, like in the Riemannian case?

Comment: Yes, the Hessian **matrix** is not well-defined. What you need is the more abstract concept of the [Hessian tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Generalizations_to_Riemannian_manifolds), which may be regarded as an object which is *represented* by matrices obeying a certain change of coordinates law, although that's a rather old-fashioned point of view.

Comment: But to summarize, the answers to all the questions in your post are a clear "no", as your own answer demonstrates.